# Jquery ui range slider set dynamic min and max with given value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uislider

I have to implement jquery ui slider in my asap.

Min : 02 12 18 21 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 65 75 85
Max : 11 17 20 24 29 34 39 44 49 54 64 74 84 94

above are min and max values.

I need to set min value dynamic, if user at value 2 and if user move slider then its goto 12 and then so on given values....

And max value set according to min value...

For example,

When user move slider 2 to 12 then max value move 11 to 17....

User can move max value at any point but min value is fixed.

Thanks in advance.

Any help would be appreciate..

Comment: I am newbie in jquery ui so i just put ui range slider nothing more...so please if you have any idea about ui range slider then tell me how can i achieve this functionality in ui slider....

Comment: check this URL http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Comment: hi, i have already done with this slider but i need to integrate above min and max range with ui range slider.....